# Write data to file from a list, by tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here!
I trying to write/append data from tkinter entry to a `txt` file. The entries, goes to a list, that I will append to the text file. But it doesn't take my new entry, only my already defined text.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Input
# -----------------------------------------------------
ivn = StringVar()
inputVarName = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn))
ivn.set(str("text1"))
ivnget = ivn.get()
inputVarName.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Input
# -----------------------------------------------------
ivn2 = StringVar()
inputVarName2 = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn2))
ivn2.set(str("text2"))
ivnget2 = ivn2.get()
inputVarName2.grid(row=1, column=0)


# Collecting data (entry)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
content_list = [ivnget, ivnget2]
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print("\n".join(content_list))


def writetofile():
    with open("dataoutput2.txt", "a") as f:
        for item in content_list:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)


# Button that applies entries to file
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
applyButton = Button(root, text="Apply", command=writetofile)
applyButton.grid(row=2, column=1)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed the `get` commands outside the function `writetofile`.
Try:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

ivn = StringVar()
inputVarName = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn))
ivn.set(str("text1"))
inputVarName.grid(row=0, column=0)

ivn2 = StringVar()
inputVarName2 = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn2))
ivn2.set(str("text2"))
inputVarName2.grid(row=1, column=0)




def writetofile():
    content_list = [ivn.get(), ivn2.get()]

    print("\n".join(content_list))    
    with open("dataoutput2.txt", "a") as f:
        for item in content_list:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

applyButton = Button(root, text="Apply", command=writetofile)
applyButton.grid(row=2, column=1)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! :D I think I understand the solution! You deleted my variables ivnget and applied the get method to the list instead!